# X11 initialization failed

Tags: php, python, centos

есть php-скрипт, который вызывает питон-скрипт через `exec`,
в питон-скрипте используется `Skype4py`.

если этот скрипт запустить через ssh, то получаем ошибку:

> dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

как её победить, я не смог найти.

но если мы запускаем скрипт через графический терминал, подключившись к серверу по удаленному рабочему столу, то скрипт отрабатывает прекрасно.

мне же нужно, чтобы скрипт запускался вообще извне, через nginx, и он не работает так же, как и через ssh.

решил обойти проблему с другой стороны: запустить скрипт с бесконечным циклом `php -f` в графическом терминале, и синхронизировать его с тем, что будет вызываться через веб.

и тут меня подстерегла неудача: в графическом терминале `php -f` уже не работает так же, как и через ssh.

что за разница такая? и как это побороть?

Answer (score 1):

> X11 initialization failed

это свидетельствует о том, что программе, которую вы пытаетесь выполнить, нужно общаться с *x*-сервером. ну, так уж она написана. наверно, хочет что-нибудь нарисовать на экране.

для этого пользователем, под имененем которого вы подключаетесь, должна быть запущена *x*-сессия (выполнен т.н. «графический вход в систему»). после этого вашей программе нужно только «подсказать», к какому именно *x*-серверу ей следует подключаться (ведь их может быть запущено и несколько, например, если несколько пользователей выполнили т.н. «графический вход в систему»).

если это единственный пользователь, который запускает *x*-сессию, то *x*-сервер (как правило) будет иметь номер `0`.

поэтому попробуйте запустить ваш скрипт не так:

```
$ ssh user@host /путь/к/скрипту
```

а так:

```
$ ssh user@host 'DISPLAY=:0 /путь/к/скрипту'
```

Comment: вы исправили вопрос, тем самым потерялся смысл.
исправить ошибку X11 initialization failed невозможно.
и вопрос заключался в том, как запустить скрипт в бесконечном цикле, аналогично обычному вызову его в графическом терминале, но не вешая его.
если запустить через графический терминал php -f *** & он так же не срабатывает.

Comment: что значит «не срабатывает?».